# Ubuntu 16.04: cannot download any software & updates

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation

I cannot install any program in Ubuntu 16.04 because of this error:

```
a@a-HP-Compaq-dc7800-Convertible-Minitower:~$ sudo apt-get install krita
[sudo] password for a:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find   
 an archive for it.
a@a-HP-Compaq-dc7800-Convertible-Minitower:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

In case this does not work, try that:

```
sudo apt-get -o 'Dpkg::Option::=force-remove-reinstreq' purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```